# Why can't I use direct instance variable from parent class

Tags: objective-c, class

```
@interface rectangle: NSObject
@property int width, height;
{
     -(int) area;
     -(int) perimeter;
     -(void) setWidth: (int) w andHeight: (int) h;
}
@end

@implementation rectangle
@synthesize width, height;
...
...
@end
```

I made a square subclass of rectangle

```
@interface square: rectangle
-(void) setSide: (int) s;
-(int) side;
@end


@implementation square
-(void) setSide: (int) s
{
    [self setWidth: s andHeight: s];
}
-(int) side
{
    return self.width;
}

@end
```

My main question is this: Why can't I just do this

```
return width;
```

when I want to get the side of my square object.
I thought

```
@property int width, height;
```

is just a simplified from

```
@interface rectangle: NSObject
{
    int width;
    int height;
}
//getter/setter methods
...
@end
```

and in the book, if an instance variable is declared in @interface, it is inherited by its subclass. But, apparently,

```
return width;
```

doesn't seem to work. Why is this happening?

Comment: A property is certainly not a "simplified form" of an instance variable.

Comment: is variable declared in property a private variable?

Comment: A property is more than that. A property makes the setter and getter accessible and it defines some key behaviour of the accessors (eg. copy vs. assign results in slightly different setters). AND the property makes it accessible from outside. As you work with @synthesize your corresponging iVar should be `width`, the way you use it. If you just declare the property, which you should, and let the compiler autosynthesize it then the corresponding protected ivar's name would be `_width.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd: also, a property need not be backed by an instance variable at all

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that synthesize of properties is part of the implementation, not the interface.  The subclass can only rely on the interface.

For example, the `@synthesize` *could have* specified a different instance variable name (e.g. `@synthesize width = _my_funky_width;`) and the subclass would have no way of knowing what the actual instance variable was.